# obtain the phase between two signals

Tags: signal-processing

I would like to calculate the phase between two signals like

```
f= Table[Sin[x-0.8],{x,-100,100,0.1}]
g= Table[Sin[x],{x,-100,100,0.1}]
```

For doing that I use the `ArcCos[Correlation[f, g]]`, that instruction gives the phase between two functions but is independent of the sign of the phase. There is some way to consider the sign of the phase?

Thanks

Comment: No, they use the same function.

Comment: @F.Mark I don’t understand what you mean. The question linked by Marius seems to fit your problem exactly! Can you explain why that solution would not work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A phase of 45.6991 degrees? Followed Mariusz's advice, the graph shows different. (19? degrees)

```
f = Table[Sin[x - 0.8], {x, -100, 100, 0.1}];
g = Table[Sin[x], {x, -100, 100, 0.1}];

ffts1B = Fourier[f, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}];
ffts2B = Fourier[g, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}];
maxB = Max[Abs[ffts1B]];
posB = First[First[Position[Abs[ffts1B], maxB]]];
Arg[ffts1B[[posB]]] - Arg[ffts2B[[posB]]]

%/Pi*180
(* Out 45.6991 *)
aplt = ListLinePlot[{f, g}, PlotRange -> {{0, 100.0}, {-1.1, 1.1}}]
```

[image: graphic of plot from original data]

Seeing your Trig.

```
Sin[x-0.8] - Sin[x-0.0]
In:= 0.2*Pi/2/Pi*180
(* Out= 18. *)
```

My guess at the answer? 18 degrees.